# ColorLuminance wrong colors

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Trying to set color ranges to chart  [code][1]

But on small ranges ColorLuminance give wrong colors

[image]

So how to fix wrong colors?

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/906ff7c230408f36094735a8203d2aad?editors=0010
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extremely small ranges and a large variance, so of course the colors will appear extremely dark with those settings. The algorithm tries to create a color from your value based on your range and a luminance, which is derived from the your variance divided by the column value times the average in the range. For your yellow and green ranges, the calculated luminance is usually way above 1 when it normally should be a value between 0-1, which is why it goes from yellow/green to black very easily.

Setting the variation values to much smaller decimals will fix this:

```
  "colorRanges": [{
    "start": -1,
    "end": 0,
    "color": "#FF0000",
    "variation": 0.4,
    "valueProperty": "visits",
    "colorProperty": "color"
  }, {
    "start": .001,
    "end": .150,
    "color": "#FFFF00",
    "variation": 0.1,
    "valueProperty": "visits",
    "colorProperty": "color"
  }, {
    "start": .151,
    "end": 1,
    "color": "#008000",
    "variation": 0.2,
    "valueProperty": "visits",
    "colorProperty": "color"
  }],
```

Demo below:

```js
/**
 * AmCharts plugin: Auto-calculate color based on value
 * The plugin relies on custom chart propety: `colorRanges`
 */
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

  var dataProvider = chart.dataProvider;
  var colorRanges = chart.colorRanges;

  // Based on https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/
  function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {

    // validate hex string
    hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
    if (hex.length < 6) {
      hex = hex[0] + hex[0] + hex[1] + hex[1] + hex[2] + hex[2];
    }
    lum = lum || 0;

    // convert to decimal and change luminosity
    var rgb = "#",
      c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      c = parseInt(hex.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
      c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
      rgb += ("00" + c).substr(c.length);
    }

    return rgb;
  }

  if (colorRanges) {

    var item;
    var range;
    var valueProperty;
    var value;
    var average;
    var variation;
    for (var i = 0, iLen = dataProvider.length; i < iLen; i++) {

      item = dataProvider[i];

      for (var x = 0, xLen = colorRanges.length; x < xLen; x++) {

        range = colorRanges[x];
        valueProperty = range.valueProperty;
        value = item[valueProperty];

        if (value >= range.start && value <= range.end) {
          average = (range.start - range.end) / 2;

          if (value <= average)
            variation = (range.variation * -1) / value * average;
          else if (value > average)
            variation = range.variation / value * average;

          item[range.colorProperty] = ColorLuminance(range.color, variation.toFixed(2));
        }
      }
    }
  }

}, ["serial"]);

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "colorRanges": [{
    "start": -1,
    "end": 0,
    "color": "#FF0000",
    "variation": 0.4,
    "valueProperty": "visits",
    "colorProperty": "color"
  }, {
    "start": .001,
    "end": .150,
    "color": "#FFFF00",
    "variation": 0.1,
    "valueProperty": "visits",
    "colorProperty": "color"
  }, {
    "start": .151,
    "end": 1,
    "color": "#008000",
    "variation": 0.2,
    "valueProperty": "visits",
    "colorProperty": "color"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": -.01
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": .01
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": -0.1809
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 0.02
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 0.149
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": .1114
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": .984
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": -.711
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": .15
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": .0151
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": .155
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": .411
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": .395
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 0
  }],
  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "visits",
    "colorField": "color"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 20
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```